# How can I add directional arrows to lines drawn on a map in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, maps, data-visualization, geosphere

I've got a map that I've built using the `maps` and `geosphere` packages that looks like an airline map. However, I'd like to add arrows to the lines to show the directions of the "routes" in my map. You can see my current working code below (based off of the fabulous tutorial from [FlowingData](http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/)). I've tried before to use the arrows function in lieu of the lines function, yet I'm not sure how to make the arrows go with the geosphere curve, or ensure that the arrows are spaced along the line so that they look like this:

-->-->-->

I'm incredibly new to R, so any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
read.csv("http://marsiccr.github.io/Data/airports.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) -> airports
read.csv("http://marsiccr.github.io/Data/leaders.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) -> flights
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("#f2f2f2", "blue"))
colors <- pal(100)
colleges<-NULL
colleges$name <- airports$insname
colleges$long <- airports$long
colleges$lat <- airports$lat
colleges
map("state")
map("state", col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.25)
fsub <- flights[flights$type == "aau",]
fsub <- fsub[order(fsub$cnt),]
maxcnt <- max(fsub$cnt)
for (j in 1:length(fsub$type)) {
  air1 <- airports[airports$unitid == fsub[j,]$school1,]
  air2 <- airports[airports$unitid == fsub[j,]$school2,]
  inter <- gcIntermediate(c(air1[1,]$long, air1[1,]$lat), c(air2[1,]$long, air2[1,]$lat), n=100, addStartEnd=TRUE)
  colindex <- round( (fsub[j,]$cnt / maxcnt) * length(colors) )
  lines(inter, col=colors[colindex], lwd=0.8)
}
```

Comment: the urls in the code return 404 not found, could you please give a new, reproducible example? that would help

Answer (score 0):

Slipping this code into the for-loop just after `inter<-` got me arrowheads (and a few warnings)

```
tinter <- tail(inter,2)
arrows(tinter[1,1], tinter[1,2], tinter[2,1], tinter[2,2])
```

[image]

Obviously there's some tweaking to be done. See `?arrows`for the full range of options. You could also use the second to last (or the fifth to last?) points in the `inter` matrix. You might also want to onlyy put in arrowheads for selected routes.